# Align children with first child in Column

Tags: flutter

How can I align my widget to take the same width as ClipRect image?
Right now it overflows in my screen. Find attached how it is and how I desire my output would be.
Is it possible to center it within the red lines I drew?

[image]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mainChildKey = GlobalKey();
    return Flexible(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ColumnWithMainChild(
            mainChildKey: mainChildKey,
            children: [
              ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              child: Image.network(
                imgparam,
                width: 350,
                height: 200,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),

          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 8, 0, 8),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Good with children: $param_good_children',
                          
                        ),
                        GFProgressBar(
                          width: 150,
                          percentage: 0.3,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                          progressBarColor: Colors.red,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Divider(),
                    Text(
                      'Good with children: $param_good_children',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following Changes

1. Set Padding to Parent column
2. Set width of NetworkImage to double.infinity
3. Wrap your Progress Bar with Flexible

Code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mainChildKey = GlobalKey();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding( // Set Padding to Paren
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            child: Image.network(
              "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474922651267-219b23864ae8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80",
              width: double.infinity, // Set width of NetworkImage to double.infinity
              height: 200,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 8, 0, 8),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Good with children: 5',
                      ),
                      Flexible( //Wrap your Progress Bar with Flexible
                        child: GFProgressBar(
                          width: 150,
                          percentage: 0.3,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                          progressBarColor: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  const Divider(),
                  const Text(
                    'Good with children: 5',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Output:

[image: Output Image]